# Small circle to be overwritten by text

Tags: tikz-pgf, kerning

How would I define a command that draws a small circle, centered at that position in the text, by which it is then overwritten. I would wish to produce something resembling the following image by a sequence such as `Te\myredcircle{}xt`.:

[image: circle overwritten by text]

My intended use for it would be to unobstructively show landmarks, such as  line or page breaks of different sources of my text in a critical edition.  I've tagged my question with `tikz-pgf` as I believe this might be a possible tool to be used for it, I'm not sure it is, though.

Update: Seing that any solution using tikz takes quite a bit longer to compile, and the circle not being that complex I thought of a solution not using it, and arrived at one which almost satisfies, but I would still like the circle to be centered at the point at which the command is, not just beginning. I tried  splitting the negative kerning before and after the circle, which does shift it to the desired position, but then covers parts of the letters preceding it. That part seems to be tricky. Oh, and the circle is just an example, probably later I'll use some other symbol.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{calc}
\newcommand\redcircle{{\huge\textcolor{red}{$\bullet$}}}
\newlength{\circlelength}
\setlength{\circlelength}{\widthof{\redcircle}}
\newcommand\myredcircle{\redcircle{}\kern -\circlelength}

\begin{document}
Some te\myredcircle{}xt.  Some more text.
\end{document}
```

[image: another try]

Comment: Your desired syntax, `Te\myredcircle{}xt` makes things much tougher, as it forces the drawing of the red circle *after* (i.e., atop) the "Te" has been typeset.  Is alternative syntax allowed, such as `\myredcircle{Text}`?

Answer (score 7):

Use `picture` mode.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{picture}(0,0)
  \put(0,3){\color{red}\circle*{50}}
  \put(0,0){\hbox to 0pt{\hss Text\hss}}
\end{picture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Look! A downvote.  Well, I also don't like `picture` mode that much.

Answer (score 6):

Using `tikzmark`, we can put a mark on the page where you want the circle to be and then draw it "afterwards", only using a bit of shipout wizardry the "afterwards" magically becomes "before".

(Note: I'm not an expert in shipout matters so I don't guarantee that this bit of shipouttery doesn't break something crucial.  Others may be able to fix or reassure on that.

I use L3 because it makes life easier as a programmer, but there doesn't seem to be an L3 native way of hooking into the shipout toks and I'm not sure what the L3 version of `\newtoks` is.  Again, hopefully an expert can weigh in on that.)

Due to the use of `tikzmark`, it needs two runs to place the circles in the right places.

[image: tikzmark circle]

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/312691/86}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\seq_new:N \l__page_marks_seq
\seq_new:N \l__page_marks_tmp_seq

\int_new:N \l__page_marks_int
\int_zero:N \l__page_marks_int

\DeclareDocumentCommand \Circle {} {
  \int_gincr:N \l__page_marks_int
  \tikzmark{circle-\int_use:N \l__page_marks_int}
  \seq_gpush:NV \l__page_marks_seq \l__page_marks_int
}

\tl_const:Nx \c__colon_tl { \token_to_str:N : }


\DeclareDocumentCommand \doCircles {} {
  \seq_clear:N \l__page_marks_tmp_seq
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l__page_marks_seq {
    \iftikzmark{circle-##1}{
      \int_compare:nT { \use:c {save@pg@\use:c{save@pt@circle-##1}} == \value{page}} {
        \tikz[remember~ picture,overlay] \fill[red] (pic~ cs\tl_use:N \c__colon_tl circle-##1) ++(0,6pt) circle [radius=6pt];
      }
    }{
      \seq_push:Nn \l__page_marks_tmp_seq {##1}
    }
  }
  \seq_gset_eq:NN \l__page_marks_seq \l__page_marks_tmp_seq
}


\newtoks\orig_output
\orig_output=\output
\output={%
  \setbox255=\vbox
  {
    \doCircles
    \unvbox255
  }
  \the\orig_output
}

\ExplSyntaxOff



\begin{document}

Te\Circle xt

\newpage

Some more te\Circle xt.

\newpage

Yet more text that should have a ci\Circle rcle in it.

\end{document}
```

---

*Updated 4th June 2016*

The OP has expressed a preference for a non-TikZ solution.  The following replaces `tikzmark` with `zref-savepos` and `tikz` with `textblock` and uses the OPs circle code.  Otherwise, it is essentially the same solution as above.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/312691/86}

\usepackage[user,savepos]{zref}
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{calc}

\newcommand\redcircle{{\huge\textcolor{red}{$\bullet$}}}
\newlength{\circlelength}
\setlength{\circlelength}{\widthof{\redcircle}}
\newcommand\myredcircle{\redcircle{}\kern -\circlelength}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\makeatletter
\cs_set_eq:NN \zref_get_prop:nn \zref@extract
\makeatother

\seq_new:N \l__page_marks_seq
\seq_new:N \l__page_marks_tmp_seq

\int_new:N \l__page_marks_int
\int_zero:N \l__page_marks_int

\DeclareDocumentCommand \Circle {} {
  \int_gincr:N \l__page_marks_int
  \zsavepos{circle-pos-\int_use:N \l__page_marks_int}
  \zlabel{circle-page-\int_use:N \l__page_marks_int}
  \seq_gpush:NV \l__page_marks_seq \l__page_marks_int
}

\tl_const:Nx \c__colon_tl { \token_to_str:N : }

\dim_new:N \l__page_marks_x_dim
\dim_new:N \l__page_marks_y_dim
\dim_new:N \l__page_marks_w_dim
\dim_set:Nn \l__page_marks_w_dim {\circlelength}


\DeclareDocumentCommand \doCircles {} {
  \group_begin:
  \seq_clear:N \l__page_marks_tmp_seq
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l__page_marks_seq {
    \int_compare:nTF {\zref_get_prop:nn {circle-page-##1} {page} == \value{page}}
    {
    \dim_set:Nn \l__page_marks_x_dim {\zposx{circle-pos-##1} sp}
    \dim_set_eq:NN \l__page_marks_y_dim \pdfpageheight
    \dim_sub:Nn \l__page_marks_y_dim {\zposy{circle-pos-##1} sp}
      \begin{textblock*}{\dim_use:N \l__page_marks_w_dim}[0.5,1](\dim_use:N \l__page_marks_x_dim, \dim_use:N \l__page_marks_y_dim)
    \noindent \myredcircle
      \end{textblock*}
    }
    {
      \seq_push:Nn \l__page_marks_tmp_seq {##1}
    }
  }
  \seq_gset_eq:NN \l__page_marks_seq \l__page_marks_tmp_seq
  \group_end:
}


\newtoks\orig_output
\orig_output=\output
\output={%
  \setbox255=\vbox
  {
    \doCircles
    \unvbox255
  }
  \the\orig_output
}

\ExplSyntaxOff



\begin{document}

Te\Circle xt

\newpage

Some more te\Circle xt.

\newpage

Yet more text that should have a ci\Circle rcle in it.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Excellent!  With adherence to OP's syntax.

Comment: I tried to adapt your solution to one of my files, and the first thing I noticed was a compile time of 12 minutes for the first run for this 500 pages document. Further runs were only around one and a half minutes, when normally it is just less than a minute. I was warned that tikz would slow down things, but particularly the first run is really too long. Is it normal, or is it an indication of something being wrong?

Comment: Then also the circles didn't appear in the places I would expect them. Sometimes they would appear even in the margins. There might be a conflict with reledmac which also needs several runs until things settle, or something else. I guess next I should do a little bit less minimal example more resembling my actual files in structure, but I'm really worried about the compile time issue...

Comment: @muk.li What happens if you just do `\usepackage{tikz}` in your document with no other changes?  I find a hike to 12 minutes quite surprising, but with little other data it's hard to know why that occurred.  I've never heard of `reledmac`, let alone used it, so I don't know if there's a conflict there.  How many circles are in the document?

Comment: @muk.li See edit.

Comment: Your new version doesn't compile here, stops with `ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   {
l.83 \newpage`

Comment: @muk.li At this point, I'm wondering where you get your tex packages from.  I'm using TeXLive 2015 and all of the packages I've used in that version are standard ones in that distribution.

Comment: I also use TeX Live 2015, however I use xelatex. I could compile your new example with pdflatex, after that further runs were successful also with xelatex.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a **non-ideal**, yet simple method, using the syntax requested by the OP, `Te\myredcircle{}xt`.  It draws the circle with opacity, so that what was written prior (the "Te" in this case) can still be seen, though occluded.  That may or may not be acceptable, based on your application.

As mentioned in my comment to the OP, the requested syntax is tough to work with, since it requests the circle only after prior text has been set, without advance warning.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\myredcircle{\smash{\raisebox{-5pt}{\makebox[0pt]{%
  \tikz\node[inner sep=0pt, opacity=0.4]{\textcolor{red}{%
  \scalebox{3.3}{$\bullet$}}};}}}}
\begin{document}
\sffamily
Te\myredcircle{}xt
\end{document}
```

[image]

If an altered syntax is allowed, `\myredcircle{Te}xt`, so that the macro know what text **NOT** to overwrite, it becomes easier:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\myredcircle[1]{\leavevmode\phantom{#1}\smash{\raisebox{-5pt}{\makebox[0pt]{%
  \tikz\node[inner sep=0pt]{\textcolor{red}{%
  \scalebox{3.3}{$\bullet$}}};}}}\llap{#1}}
\begin{document}
\sffamily
\myredcircle{Te}xt
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your first solution is almost there, and the compile time is only 30% increased, which might be o.k.. I still have to think if the altered syntax is possible also, as that obviously does make things easier.

Answer (score 4):

One more with TikZ:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
rdt/.style args = {#1/#2}%rdt: red dot text
    {shape=circle, fill=red, 
     minimum size=#2, inner sep=0.2ex,
     label={[font=\sffamily,text depth=0.25ex]center:#1}, 
     node contents={\vphantom{gh}}}
                    ]
\node[rdt=Text/2ex];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Second argument determine size of circle (how many character lie on the circle).

Comment: Why is the kerning between `T` and `e` so bad?

Comment: Seems like it is just that way.  The red dot merely amplifies the visual effect.

Comment: if you replace T with t, the visual effect is changed, dots is seems to be better centered but position of the label is the same.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a short solution with `pstricks` and `xstring`. I define a `\InsertCircle` command, with an optional argument (the number of characters before the circle is inserted) and a mandatory argument (the string).

```
\documentclass[12pt, x11names, border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node} \usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand\InsertCircle[2][1]{\begin{postscript}\pnode{Ins}\StrLeft{#2}{#1}\Cnode*[linecolor=Tomato1, radius=1.6ex](0, 0.5ex){A}\rput[Bl](Ins){#2}\end{postscript}}

\begin{document}

\InsertCircle[2]{Text}

\end{document}
```

[image]